# How to put the BigQuery table data in Dropdown in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-bigquery

I'm very newbie to Javascript . I've been stacked in making dynamic dropdown with BigQuery table data in Node.js . I've already got table data from BigQuery and made static dropdown but I have no idea how to put the table data in dropdown. Anyone help me ?? Sorry for my poor code.

index.js

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  
const bigquery = new BigQuery({
    projectId: 'test_project',
});

bigquery
    .dataset("test_table")
    .getTables()
    .then(results => {
        const tables = results[0];
        tables.forEach(table => console.log(table.id));
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });

const list = ["I want to put table data(tables) in here"];
// select tag
let slt = document.getElementById("slt");
addTables(slt);

// return data 
function getList() {
  return new Promise(function (onFulliflled, onRejected) {
    onFulliflled(list);
  });
}

function addTables(slt) {
  getList()
    .then((list) => {
      for (item of list) {
        // make option
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = item;
        option.value = item;

        // add option
        slt.appendChild(option);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("error", err);
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>sample</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h3>Please choose table</h3>
      <select id="slt" name="slt"></select>
      <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this prom with below code

```
function listTables(callback) {
    //...

        .then(results => {
            const tables = results[0];
            tables.forEach(table => list.push(table.id));
            callback(list);
        })
    //...
}

listTables(function(list){

});
```